# Powershell New-PSSession issue

Tags: powershell, winrm

When I remote desktop to a box I will get a prompt like this:

[image]

Once I select **"Yes"** I am connected to the box. When I try to login to the same box with the same credentials in PowerShell I get the error listed at the end of this post.

```
$secPasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $secPasswd)
$session = New-PSSession –ComputerName $hst -Credential $creds
```

where $hst is "MyBox" and $username is "MyBox\MyUser"

**Q: Is there a way in powershell for me to mimic the selection of the "Yes" button?**

**ERROR:**

> New-PSSession : [MyBox] Connecting to remote server MyBox failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: There are 
>   currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.
>
> Possible causes are:
>
> - The user name or password specified are invalid.
> - Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
> - Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
> - The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
> - The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
>
> After checking for the above issues, try the following:
>
> - Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
> - Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
>
> Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
>
> - For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

**Analysis on target box**

- WinRM is running
- Expected firewall rules are in place
- User is part of the admin group
- PSRemoting is enabled

Comment: you are mixing up **RDP** (remote desktop protocol) and **winrm** (windows remote management ) those are completly independants

Comment: The error message lists several possible causes and things to try. Did you double check that the credentials are valid? Did you follow the troubleshooting steps outlined [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jonjor/archive/2009/01/09/winrm-windows-remote-management-troubleshooting.aspx)? What does the eventlog on the remote host say?

Comment: The credentials are valid as I could login via Remote Desktop. I used the same credentials for the powershell session. There was no entry in the Eventlog of note. I checked the System logs.

Comment: does it work if you create the credentials using Get-Credential? Does $username include the domain name?

Comment: It does not work using Get-Credential failing with the same error, $username does indeed contain the domain name.

Comment: In the end this was down to **"The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains."** and was resolved by having the client add the box to it's trusted sources using **Set-Item wsman:localhost\client\trustedhosts "MyBox"**

Comment: FTR, logon events are recorded in the Security eventlog, not the System eventlog.